# extract path between single quotes using grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep, wget

I'm using wget to download files and during the process, I save log messages (see below) for later use.
The most important part is this line   `Saving to: ‘/path/somefile.gz’`.

I figured out, how I can extract this snipped using `grep Saving`.
**Now, my question is:**  how can I extract just the path between the single quotes? `‘/path/somefile.gz’ => /path/somefile.gz`

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 15391 (15K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/path/somefile.gz’

     0K .......... .....                                      100% 79,7M=0s

2020-07-06  - ‘/path/somefile.gz’ saved [15391/15391]


Total wall clock time: 0,1s
Downloaded: 1 files, 15K in 0s (79,7 MB/s)
```

**EDIT**

Is there any way to process it already in this form?

```
wget -m --no-parent -nd https://someurl/somefile.gz -P ~/src/  2>&1 |
grep Saving |
tee ~/src/log.txt
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `-O output_file` to save to a known path, then you don't have to parse the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question asks for a solution in `grep`, a single GNU `grep` command to extract the specified path could be:

```
grep -Po "^Saving to: .\\K[^']*"
```

provided the Perl Regular Expressions are implemented in the `grep` (not all `grep`s implement those).

Of course, it can be used in a pipe also:

```
wget_command | grep -Po "^Saving to: .\\K[^']*" | tee log.txt
```

Note that I used a single quote (`'`) character to anchor the end of path in the pattern match expression, but in the question, Unicode Character Left Single Quotation Mark (U+2018) (`‘`) and Unicode Character Right Single Quotation Mark (U+2019) (`’`) are used in the sample input. If this is really intended then just replace the `[^']` with the `[^’]` in the pattern match expression above.

Answer (score 4):

Sample output from `wget`:

```
$ cat wget.out
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 15391 (15K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: '/path/somefile.gz'

     0K .......... .....                                      100% 79,7M=0s

2020-07-06  - 'path/somefile.gz' saved [15391/15391]


Total wall clock time: 0,1s
Downloaded: 1 files, 15K in 0s (79,7 MB/s)
```

One `awk` solution to extract the desired path/file:

```
$ awk -F"'" '                        # define input delimiter as single quote
/Saving to:/   { print $2 }          # if line contains string "Saving to:" then print 2nd input field
' wget.out                           # our input
/path/somefile.gz                    # our output
```

To save the above to a variable:

```
$ wget_path=$(awk -F"'" '/Saving to:/ {print $2}' wget.out)
$ echo "${wget_path}"
/path/somefile.gz
```

---

Following up on OP's edit to the question ... piping the output of `wget` into the `awk` solution:

```
wget -m --no-parent -nd https://someurl/somefile.gz -P ~/src/ 2>&1 | awk -F"'" '/Saving to:/ {print $2}' | tee ~/src/log.txt
```